# WinSCP - Unknown command and '.log' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: powershell, batch-file, environment-variables, sftp, winscp

**Context:** I'm using powershell to instantiate a batch file to execute the synchronize remote command in WinSCP and pull in fresh data from a remote directory to my local directory. See screenshots below for contents of the WinSCP commands and the batch file contents.
When I try to execute I am able to successfully authenticate but I see 2 errors.

Batch file contents:

```
winscp.com /script=winscp_commands_ar_history.txt
/log=C:/Users/REDACTED/Desktop/AR_History_Report/winscp_log_ar_history.txt
```

WinSCP commands:

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open sftp://REDACTED:REDACTED@sftp.REDACTED.com
-hostkey="ssh-rsa 2048 cc:ea:2e:03:96:ca:e7:c0:59:74:13:a8:XX:XX:XX:XX"
synchronize remote /export/GroupAccess/REDACTED/Cognos Reporting/CogTest
C:/Users/REDACTED/Desktop/AR_History_Report
exit
```

Powershell output:
[image]

Errors:

> Unknown command '-hostkey=ssh-rsa 2048 cc:ea:2e:03:96:ca:e7:c0:59:74:13:a8:XX:XX:XX:XX'.

> '/log' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

**Question:** How do I resolve these 2 errors? I suspect the last one is related to environment variables since it seems powershell didn't recognize the WinSCP log command so I've added WinSCP to my PATH environment variable but I'm still getting the same errors. Can someone please assist? Thank you.

Comment: Just one more tip.  We normally prefer you post text as text instead of posting screenshots of it.  A lot easier to redact as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both your batch file and WinSCP script have line breaks in the middle of commands. Moreover, in the `synchronize` command you need to [wrap the path with spaces to double quotes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#quotes).

The batch file should be:

```
winscp.com /script=winscp_commands_ar_history.txt /log=C:/Users/REDACTED/Desktop/AR_History_Report/winscp_log_ar_history.txt
```

And the script file should be:

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open sftp://REDACTED:REDACTED@sftp.REDACTED.com -hostkey="ssh-rsa 2048 cc:ea:2e:03:96:ca:e7:c0:59:74:13:a8:XX:XX:XX:XX"
synchronize remote "/export/GroupAccess/REDACTED/Cognos Reporting/CogTest" C:/Users/REDACTED/Desktop/AR_History_Report
exit
```

As an aside, as @mklement0 commented, you don't need another `powershell` process to invoke a batch file from PowerShell - just invoke batch files directly: `.\ar_trigger_history.bat`

Comment: thank you this seems to resolve those errors